How do you tackle situation, when avro-maven-plugin stringType configuration changes avro schema?
Consider schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Whatever",
  "namespace": "really.whatever",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "supergotcha",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

and avro-maven-plugin configuration:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>schema</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
          <stringType>String</stringType>
          ...
          <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

when we ran this, generated Whatever SpecificRecord class will contain in field org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ this:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Whatever",
  "namespace": "really.whatever",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "supergotcha",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
    }
  ]
}

And this is a little bit problematic. Because you fetch schema, build it, and if schema-registry isn't configured exactly the same (which kinda defies the purpose) the method io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient#getId(java.lang.String, io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.ParsedSchema) will not find the schema! Since this methods searches using full schema.
What solutions I know:
a) don't specify stringType and enjoy working with java.lang.Charsequence (painful)
b) do specify "avro.java.string" in avro schema, which is inappropriate, since schema need not to be used by java only
c) configure use.latest.version=true which will fetch the newest schema from schema-registry, but it implies need for fully transitive compatibility (since newer )
any other idea? To me only valid approach seems to be A.
avro 1.11.0
